# C# Парсинг курса через плагин Polly

Tags: c#, парсер

Хочу сделать парсер курса валюты на C# с использованием nuget плагина Polly
Добраться хочу до этого значения **"/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/article/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]"**

Ныне имеется такой код:

```
public static decimal GetRate(string html)
{
    string rate = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(html, $@"<option value=""([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"">USD</option>").Groups[1].Value;
    return decimal.Parse(rate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

public async void GetCurrency(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using HttpClient client = new();
    AsyncPolicy retryForever = Policy.Handle<Exception>().RetryForeverAsync();
    string html = await retryForever.ExecuteAsync(() => client.GetStringAsync(htmllink));
    usdcur = GetRate(html);
    label1.Text = $"{usdcur}";
}
```

Как мне получить то значение, парсинг идёт с сайта " https://myfin.by/currency/gomel ";
P.S хочу получить значение курса доллара сша, на главной страницы, из категории продажа

Comment: Причём тут Polly, если ваш вопрос состоит в том, [как распарсить html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%20html)

Comment: `//div[@id="bank_valute1-styler"]//option[text() = "USD"]`

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вы не думали о том, чтоб использовать готовое апи какого-либо сервиса? Пример https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs/c-sharp-currency-api Ещё пример https://stackoverflow.com/q/53341259/13123688

Comment: https://devhints.io/xpath

Comment: вот например HtmlAgilityPack `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new(); doc.LoadHtml(html); string rate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id="bank_valute1-styler"]//option[text() = "USD"]").InnerText.Trim();`